# Regex: Matching on an exclusive either/or

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want a regex that will match for strings of `RACE` or `RACE_1`, but not `RACE_2` and `RACE_3`. I've been on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for a while now trying to figure it out, but can't seem to get all the conditions I need met. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What about `RACE_10` or `RACE_CAR`?  Should the regex match those?

Comment: No, it should not, though the options are of a known set

Comment: It's expected on Stack Overflow that you provide code showing your work. It's easier for us to help you learn if we can reference your code, and show what went wrong. Simply asking for someone to write it for you isn't what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: the relevant code was simply a regex `/RACE/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/RACE(?!_)|RACE_1/`

Its a bit of a hack but might fit your needs

EDIT:
Here might be a more specific one that works better
`/RACE(?!_\d)|RACE_1/`

In both cases, you use negative lookahead to enforce that RACE cannot be followed by `_` and a number, but then specifically allow it with the or statement following.

Also, if you plan on only searching for instances of said matches that are whole words, prepend/append with \b to designate word boundaries.

`/\bRACE(?!_\d)|RACE_1\b/`

Comment: a bit of a hack is fine with me : )

Answer (score 3):

```
/^RACE(_1)?$/
```

[Rubular example here](http://rubular.com/r/OStEsRwJGq)

Answer (score 3):

```
RACE(_1)?\b
```

\b means the end of a word, and that prevents matching RACE in RACE_2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
`(\bRACE(_[1])?\b)`

It requires the one copy of `RACE`, and then `0 -> N` occurrences of the `_[1]`.  In the square brackets you can include any number you want. EXAMPLE: 
`(\bRACE(_[12345])?\b)` will match up to `RACE_5`.  You can then customize it to even skip numbers if you want `[1245]` for `RACE_1, RACE_2, RACE_4, RACE_5` but not `RACE_3`.

Comment: This will also match `TRACE_1_1_1_1`.  I think you want a `\b` on the front, and your `*` should be a `?`.  And FYI, the `{1}` has no effect.  You're telling it to match one of the previous atom, which is what it would do in the absence of a quantifier.  BTW, "previous atom" in this case means the `E`; if you wanted it to apply to the whole word you would need to use a group, same as you did with the `*`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks for the tips, so the `\b` in front makes it so the pattern needs to match from the first letter and can't start in the middle of a new line?  Updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: It prevents it from matching inside a longer word, like `GRACE` or `FOOTRACE`.  The OP didn't state that as a requirement, but I think it's to assume that's what he meant.  [Kyle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15123002/20938) is even more restrictive, requiring the matched text to be on a line by itself.